# Why Does ArrayDeque class doesnot provide implementation of all the abstract methods declared in deque Interface?

Tags: java, collections, queue, deque, arraydeque

Why Does ArrayDeque class doesnot provide implementation of the following abstract methods declared in deque Interface? - descendingIterator, peekFirst, peekLast, pollFirst, pollLast .

As per the best of my knowledge if a class implements an Interface it has to provide implementation of all the abstract methods of that Interface otherwise the class is declared as abstract class.

Reference(Link) : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

Comment: It does: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/3c9ec26370dfae5d1230b6b69ae26122fe42e51d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#L416. Looks like it just doesn't directly show up in the Javadoc because those methods have no Javadoc comments in the source code. That typically means the documentation from the superclass/interface sufficiently documents the behavior (you can see the methods exist under "Methods declared in interface java.util.Deque").

Comment: Thanks for educating me,just confirmed the same through my Eclipse IDE.